# Weka greyed out classifers

Tags: weka

I am sorry once again to bring another question up but why is Weka is graying out some classifiers for the data which I bring about. And a sample glipse of the data file is attached as follows:

```
@relation whatever

@attribute ClearanceFactor numeric
@attribute CrestFactor numeric
@attribute HistogramLB numeric
@attribute HistogramUB numeric
@attribute ImpulseFactor numeric
@attribute KurtVal numeric
@attribute PeakVal numeric
@attribute RMSVal numeric
@attribute Status { Normal } 


@data
1 , 0.944758327 , 0.818823375 , 0.835884533 , 0.973802319 , 0.922274575 , 0.836712854 , 0.830582178 , Normal 
1 , 0.922118042 , 0.737125289 , 0.762040973 , 0.963101929 , 0.889826729 , 0.762426651 , 0.753675509 , Normal 
1 , 0.975667525 , 0.916722849 , 0.924607883 , 0.988490457 , 0.962805959 , 0.925217603 , 0.922378149 , Normal
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by a simple trick. In the last column, I added all of the other possible solution sets as follows and it worked! :D

```
@relation whatever

@attribute ClearanceFactor numeric
@attribute CrestFactor numeric
@attribute HistogramLB numeric
@attribute HistogramUB numeric
@attribute ImpulseFactor numeric
@attribute KurtVal numeric
@attribute PeakVal numeric
@attribute RMSVal numeric
@attribute Status { Normal, faulty0, faulty1}
```